# Problem with making random string in python

Tags: python

I'm semi-new to python, and i'm trying to make a random username and password generator, but nothing that I've been having trouble setting  up a random username

I've tried just generating a random string of ten characters, but it ends up being way too long, and quite repetitive. Here's the code I tried

```
class CreateAcc:
    def passwordGenerator(self):
        import random, string
        password = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for i in range(8))
        return password
    def usernameGenerator(self):
        import random, string
        nameExtra = ''.join(str(random.randint(0, 9) for i in range(2)))
        username = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for i in range(10))
        username = username.join(nameExtra)
        return username
    def main():
        print("Username: %s. Password: %s" %(self.usernameGenerator(), self.passwordGenerator()))
ca = CreateAcc()
ca.main()
```

The password works just fine, but I get a huge username, when I only want ten characters. It looks like this:

Username: xMxzISsYSg.xMxzISsYSgxMxzISsYSg xMxzISsYSgaxMxzISsYSgtxMxzISsYSg xMxzISsYSg0xMxzISsYSgxxMxzISsYSg0xMxzISsYSg0xMxzISsYSg0xMxzISsYSg0xMxzISsYSg0xMxzISsYSg2xMxzISsYSg0xMxzISsYSgBxMxzISsYSg0xMxzISsYSg9xMxzISsYSgAxMxzISsYSg5xMxzISsYSgDxMxzISsYSgExMxzISsYSg4xMxzISsYSg8xMxzISsYSg>. Password: mvomUHH6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`username.join(nameExtra)` means "take each of the characters in `nameExtra`, and put the full value of `username` between each of them". This is why it's appearing several times. To fix this problem, do `username + nameExtra` instead of `username.join(nameExtra)`.

Also, you're not building a string correctly, so it's using `<generator object CreateAcc.usernameGenerator.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0000020B09A5DE48>` as the string, instead of the text you wanted it to use. To fix this problem, do `''.join(str(random.randint(0, 9)) for i in range(2))` instead of `''.join(str(random.randint(0, 9) for i in range(2)))`. Note the subtle difference in the closing parentheses.